# JavaFx freezes after method is done

Tags: java, performance, javafx, freeze

My problem is that my JavaFx application has gone to be very slow. Both in the start of the application and in some of the triggered events. It is a calendar application that uses a `GridPane`, that I am modifying. I have this method:

```
t.setOnMouseClicked(event->{

        long starttid = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("start");
        if (markedTimeEnd != null && markedTimeStart != null) {
            colorMinutes(markedTimeStart, markedTimeEnd, Color.BLACK, bakrundWhite);
        } else if (markedTimeStart != null) {
            colorMinutes(markedTimeStart, markedTimeStart, Color.BLACK, bakrundWhite);
        }

        long tidNu = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long tid = tidNu-starttid;
        System.out.println("Print first time:\n"+tid);

        int minutTid = gridPane.getRowIndex(t);
        int timmeTimme = minutTid / 60;
        int minutMinut = minutTid - (60 * timmeTimme);
        markedTimeStart = new TidPunkt(timmeTimme, minutMinut);
        markedTimeEnd = null;

        tid = System.currentTimeMillis() -tidNu;
        tidNu = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Time for the middel calculations:\n"+tid);
        if (markedTimeEnd != null && markedTimeStart != null) {
            colorMinutes(markedTimeStart, markedTimeEnd, Color.GREEN,bakrundGren);
        } else if (markedTimeStart != null) {
            colorMinutes(markedTimeStart, markedTimeStart, Color.GREEN,bakrundGren);
        }
        event.consume();
        repaintAll();
        System.out.println("Time to end:\n"+(System.currentTimeMillis()-tidNu));
    });
```

And the code for the colorMinutes:

```
    private void colorMinutes(TidPunkt markedTimeStart, TidPunkt markedTimeEnd, Color colorText, Background colorOther) {

    System.out.println("The call is comming");

    int startBothTogether = markedTimeStart.getTimme() * 100 + markedTimeStart.getMinut();
    int endBothTogether = markedTimeEnd.getTimme() * 100 + markedTimeEnd.getMinut();

    System.out.println("Befor filter");
    gridPane.getChildren().stream()//parallelStream()
        .filter(x-> x.getId()!=null)
        .filter(y-> y.getId().matches("\\d\\d:\\d\\d"))
        .filter(pp->{
            int hoursForPart = Integer.parseInt(((Node) pp).getId().split(":")[0]);
            int miutesForPart = Integer.parseInt(((Node) pp).getId().split(":")[1]);
            int bothTogether = hoursForPart * 100 + miutesForPart;
            if (bothTogether >= startBothTogether && bothTogether <= endBothTogether)
                return true;
            else 
                return false;
        })
        .forEach(pp->{
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                System.out.println("Changing collor ----");
                if(pp instanceof Pane){
                    ((Pane) pp).setBackground(colorOther)
                }else{
                    ((Text) pp).setFill(colorText);
                }
            });
        });
}
```

But it takes very long before it is change on the screen and it freezes sometime after what I can se is the finish of these methods by the `System.out.println`. I have been trying to profile but can't figure it out(best I have come up with it that is seems to be a big call tree, of javaFx "stuff" when exiting the method). The `System.out.println` prints is:

```
start
Print first time:
0
Time for the middel calculations:
0
The call is comming
Befor filter
Time to end:
373
Changing collor ----
Changing collor ----
Changing collor ----
Changing collor ----
```

But from button press to all is being color correct it takes many seconds.

The full code can be found [here](https://github.com/flaime/DayViewJavaFX)

Comment: How many panes are inside the grid pane?

Comment: Approximately 7200 when i latest tested but it depends so can be down to approximately 2800.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're posting to many `Runnable`s using `Platform.runLater`. There is no reason to use `Platform.runLater` here at all, since the `onMouseClicked` event handler is executed on the javafx application thread anyways.

Using

```
.forEach(pp->{
    if(pp instanceof Pane){
        ((Pane) pp).setBackground(colorOther)
    }else{
        ((Text) pp).setFill(colorText);
    }
});
```

Should improve the performance drastically.

Furthermore you seem to add a huge amout of `Node`s in your `repaintAll` method (more specifically the `ritaGrundKalender` method) without removing `Node`s which increases the number of `Runnable`s for every click. I suggest you change this behavior.

Comment: Nice it did really help, thank you! But one strange thing is that the first time pressing a objekt it takes some time before it becomes green but the second times is being done immediately, do you have some idea to solve that to?

Comment: Solved it by adding a background when created them.